# Como habilitar o auto-completar em Views declarativas no Crux Framework?

Tags: java, eclipse, crux-framework

Ao criar um novo projeto (ou mesmo quando eu importo projetos já existentes) no Eclipse, como eu consigo habilitar a função de auto-completar dos componentes  nas views?

Eu tenho que importar algum catálogo, ou isso seria uma configuração no próprio Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Crux possui uma ferramenta chamada SchemaGenerator. Esta ferramenta irá criar arquivos .xsd para validar os seus arquivos de view e permitir que qualquer IDE (o Eclipse por exemplo) possa autocompletar as tags e atributos para você.

Ao criar um projeto novo com o Crux através de qualquer um de seus archetypes maven, você perceberá que na raiz do projeto será criado um arquivo chamado "Generate Schemas.launch".

Basta clicar com o botão direito sobre ele e clicar em "run As => Generate Schema". Isso irá executar a ferramenta mencionada e irá criar uma pasta na raiz do seu projeto chamada "xsd".

Dentro dela você encontrará alguns arquivos .xsd e um arquivo chamado crux-catalog.xml. Basta importar este catálogo no Eclipse que ele saberá auto-completar corretamente.

Para isso, você pode ir em File => import => XML catalog e selecionar o arquivo "crux-catalog.xml".

Para mais informações sobre este processo, consulte esta seção do manual do Crux:

http://files.cruxframework.org/crux51/single-page/index.html#sec_tools_schcema

[]s,